# Prolog exercise- need answer

Tags: prolog

Define a new infix operator is_bigger to compare the size of two animals mentioned in the facts

animals(500,xfx,is_bigger).

Is this the solution?

Answer (score 1):

To define a new operator, you need to use the ISO built-in predicate [op/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=op/3):

```
:- op(500, xfx, is_bigger_than).

elephant is_bigger_than horse.
```

Query:

```
?- X is_bigger_than Y.
X = elephant,
Y = horse.
```